# Convert existing categories to Glossary term categories

Tags: wordpress

I've just activated a glossary plugin (I'm using wordpress), and it created its own category/post term. So, the question is:

- How can i convert my existing posts/categories to the plugin category/post term?
- Do you know any wordpress plugins to do that? cause I'm very bad at coding.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185), [code fragments](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc.